# create a temporary file with a specified name in java

Tags: java, arrays, temporary-files

I have a Byte[] array that i want to put it's content into a temporary file .

I have tryied to do it like this

```
try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", null);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            fos.write(sCourrier.getBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i want that I specify the filename by myself so not generated by the jvm

Comment: You could just create a regular file and make sure you delete it after you're done with it. This way, you can name it whatever you want. You can still use the temp dir, `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`

Comment: @domdom add that as an answer

Comment: One of the purposes of a temporary file  is to ensure that you get a uniquely named file so that you don't accidentally overwrite some other program's temporary file and no other program accidentally overwrites your temporary file.  Giving a temporary file a specific name defeats this protection.  What is the real issue you are trying to overcome?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I want to display the file on my jsp on an embed tag `<embed  src="" >` so i need to have the file with his name

Comment: See my comment and/or [gati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411082/3316645) then. I'd recommend, however, to also make sure that there is no temp file with the same name already. You could easily achieve this by using a time stamp in the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly give the location and file name or You can access local filesystem and find the temp directory

```
 String tempDir=System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

you can use temp directory and your custom file name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String tempDir=System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        String sCourrier ="sahu";
        File file = new File(tempDir+"newfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(sCourrier.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava `Files.createTempDir()`:

`File file = new File(Files.createTempDir(), fileName.txt);`

But because the API is deprecated and they also recommend to use Nio with more params:

`Path createTempDirectory(String prefix, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)`

so it would be better if you have a method yourself:

```
File createTempFile(String fileName, String content) throws IOException {
        String dir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File file = new File(dir + fileName);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        return file;
    }
```